# Reinstalling new distribution

Tags: upgrade, 13.10

I had the interrupt my freezed distribution upgrade, blocked on "configuration of libthai-data". I now seem to have a sort of hybrid version, and I fear it thinks it's upgraded (lsb_release -a gives the last version).
Is there a way to:

```
- make it restart the upgrade to the last version (which I'd prefer), or
- excecute the downgrade to the previous one
```

?

Comment: Welcome to AU! You can [format simple lists](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help#simple-lists) with 0-1 spaces in front of the dash/bullet/star. Anything above 3 will be interpreted as a [code section](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) in markdown. You can edit your question with the link below it. Have a nice stay!

Answer (score 0):

try to get a older ubuntu distribution's cd and try to install it.If this fails,
Reinstall ubuntu completely.